# Which hechsheirim are reliable?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, how-to, hechsher-certification

There are so many hechsheirim (Kosher certifications) out there.

How is an individual supposed to find out which hechsheirim to rely on, and which not to?

Comment: I vote to close this as too opinion-based. There are tons of levels in hechsherim, and asking this question invites people to list those that THEY think is better than others. And all the others aren't good

Comment: I think that he is asking for a source that lists hechsheirim rather than opinions.

Comment: I think that lists or "ask your rabbi" are both valid answers to this valid and, I daresay, important question.

Comment: @mevaqesh, I think that limiting this question to only asking for lists goes too far. Lists are not necessarily even the best recourse for everyone.

Comment: The question was deemed opinion based. I think that the current version is acceptable. Whether or not it is the best way to ask the question, or the best question that should be asked, seems rather immaterial. (Not to say that it couldn't be further improved, of course) @IsaacMoses

Comment: @mevaqesh The previous version, before my edit, was so-deemed. Changing the scope of what's asked for, and cutting out an important type of potential answer, certainly does matter. I don't see why that's necessary, or even how it makes the question any more objective. I recommend reversion to the version before your edit, followed by re-opening.

Comment: @IsaacMoses I don't know why your version is so much less opinion based. (Just depersonalized). Asking for a particular list, is not, however opinion based. In my opinion :)

Comment: @mevaqesh I moved it from asking for opinion about quality ("are reliable") to asking for instructions for behavior ("to rely on"). It's a subtle change, but IMO it's sufficient to make this answerable objectively.

Answer (score 11):

"Reliable" is a loaded word.  Let's try "accepted among conventional American Orthodox standards as we know them."

A good first place to try is Rabbi Eidlitz's kosherquest list:

http://kosherquest.org/kosher-symbols/

It's not necessarily comprehensive, and occasionally people may nitpick with it, but it's a good first-order approximation.

In Israel, there's a great deal of politics.  But here's a pointer: Rabbi Dovid Miller of the Gruss Kollel has a talk he gives to new students listing which Israeli hechshers are "mehadrin", and thus recommended.  The audio is available on [YUTorah.org](http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/713654/Rabbi_Dovid_Miller/Kashrut_in_Israel_5766), and I believe the accompanying handout sheet (PDF) is floating around the internet somewhere.  I'm told that Michlalah students are given a similar (if not identical) list.

If it's a local hechsher (e.g. a restaurant certified by the Rabbinical Association of Anytown, USA), contact a local rabbi.

Generally, in the US today, a hechsher that will allow "non-Glatt" beef, such as Hebrew National, is not considered up to the standards used by most Orthodox Jews in America today.  Similarly, if it's a meat restaurant, it's open on Shabbos, and it's located someplace where the mashgiach couldn't reach it on Shabbos, that's usually a bad sign.

Otherwise, you can email the webmaster at kashrut.com, who stays in touch with lots of rabbis in the business.  The OU does not publicize which other hechshers it accepts, but I believe Chicago's [cRc might](http://www.crcweb.org/agency_list.php).

Beyond the US or Israel, try contacting a local rabbi.  Different countries can have different standards, and there's an argument to follow local standards (as long as they're within reasonable Halachic boundaries) when visiting.  The [Chavos Yair](http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/view.jsp?artid=67&letter=B) wrote of a town in Alsace where certain dried fruit required a hechsher, while it didn't elsewhere.  The Kitzur Shulchan Aruch says that some cities required a hechsher on plain butter, and some didn't, but to follow the practice of where you're located at this moment.

Comment: `Rabbi Dovid Miller of the Gruss Kollel has a talk he gives to new students listing which Israeli hechshers are "mehadrin", and thus recommended` How old is the the talk? Presumably the situation is constantly changing.

Comment: `Generally, in the US today, a hechsher that will allow "non-Glatt" beef, such as Hebrew National, is not considered up to the standards used by most Orthodox Jews in America today.` AFAIK the problem with Hebrew National transcend glatt. AFAIK "glatt" has more to do with marketing, than with the standards of halakha, or halakhists. Cf. for example, http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/43335/8775.

Answer (score 7):

In the US, I typically start with the recommended symbols lists from the [cRc](http://www.crcweb.org/agency_list.php) and the [Seattle Vaad](http://seattlevaad.org/kosher-symbols/).  Those together indicate broad acceptance.

When evaluating the status of liquors, especially European ones, I've found the [London Beth Din's directory](http://isitkosher.uk/) to be quite comprehensive.

Comment: Jonathan, Welcome to mi.yodeya, and thanks very much for these useful links.

Comment: @sabbahillel see http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit

Comment: @mevaqesh see http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit

Comment: @Dovi, welcome to Mi Yodeya. Thanks for the contributing your knowledge, but it really would be better as a separate answer: edits are for clarifying or improving what the post's author wrote, not for introducing wholly new information into a post, completely different from what its author intended. I do hope you stick around and enjoy the site.

Answer (score 3):

For Israel kosher news (with a mehadrin, charedi bent), see:
 http://www.jerusalemkoshernews.com/

For updates from the Chief Rabbinate of Israel:
http://www.dat.gov.il/%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%99+%D7%93%D7%AA/%D7%9B%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA/%D7%A2%D7%93%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%99+%D7%9B%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA/default.htm

Comment: second link is broken